# Tracking Number Link on shipment for Big Commerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I can create a shipment via the Big Commerce API - it generates the email and updates status. However, in the email there is no link for the tracking number. If you create the shipment in the admin console the resulting email/link have a link for the tracking number. Is there a way to do this via the API?

Comment: Was informed this is not possible via the API currently. Possible in future version.